# How can i use a class of WooCommerce in my custom PHP file? ( Product CSV Importer )

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, import

I've a WooCommerce website and i need to update products via CSV file automatically.
To do this, I've created a cron job that executes a PHP file and it creates a csv file each hour ( named: jsonproducts.csv).

Now, I'm planning to create a new custom PHP file which will use import() method of WC_Product_CSV_Importer class of Woocommerce. ( [Class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/import/class-wc-product-csv-importer.php) )

When i try to execute this, the result is imported: 0, failed: 0, updated:0, skipped: 0.

How can i successfully execute this?

```
<?php
include("wp-load.php");
require_once('wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/import/class-wc-product-csv-importer.php');

    
$args = array(
    'start_pos'        => 0, // File pointer start.
    'end_pos'          => 5, // File pointer end.
    'lines'            => 5, // Max lines to read.
    'mapping'          => array(), // Column mapping. csv_heading => schema_heading.
    'parse'            => true, // Whether to sanitize and format data.
    'update_existing'  => true, // Whether to update existing items.
    'delimiter'        => ',', // CSV delimiter.
    'prevent_timeouts' => false, // Check memory and time usage and abort if reaching limit.
    'enclosure'        => '"', // The character used to wrap text in the CSV.
    'escape'           => "\0", // PHP uses '\' as the default escape character. This is not RFC-4180 compliant. This disables the escape character.
);
    
$file = 'json2csv.csv';

$WC_Product_CSV_Importer = new WC_Product_CSV_Importer($file, $args);


var_dump($WC_Product_CSV_Importer->import());

?>
```

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to your problem?